# Python XML PArse with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an XML file with the following format:

```
<metadata>
    <groupId>stuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>stuff</artifactId>
    <versioning>
        <latest>stuff</latest>
        <release>stuff</release>
        <versions>
            <version>1</version>
            <version>2</version>
            <version>3</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdate>stuff</lastUpdate>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

And I have tried the following code:

```
root = ET.fromstring(data_as_string)

    for version in root.iter('versions'):
       print version.attrib
```

But it is printing 'versioning' only N times...

I'd like to be able to extract the latest version value from the highest numbered version tag which is 3. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Python script:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET 
xml = ET.parse('input.xml')
last = xml.findall("versioning/versions/version[last()]")
if len(last) > 0:
  print last[0].text
```

Its output is

> 3

which is the last `version` element.